# Cannot Find Variable 'S'. Trouble using Array with loop.

Tags: arrays, string, loops, variables

i have an Array named 'S' in a while loop i have made.

I have wrote in an input file line by line into my class; i have then managed to get the first number of each line and implement the numbers into a string Array.

Going outside of my while loop, i want to use the Array 'S' to compare the first element with the next 2 elements to see if they match.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
       int count = 0;
       FileReader Input = new FileReader("Input File");
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(Input);
       String line;
       while((line = br.readLine()) !=null)
       {
             //System.out.println(line);
             String[]bits = line.split(" +");
             String temp;
             temp = bits[1].substring(0,1);
            // System.out.println(temp);
             String S[] = temp.split(" ");
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(S));
        }
       for(int i = 0; i < S.length; i++){
           if(S[i] == S[i + 1] && S[i] == S[i + 2]){
               count++;
        }
           System.out.println(count);
```

I know my coding is horrendous. This is for the Advent of Code Puzzle, day 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have declared 'S' *within* your 'while' loop, it exists only within the context of that while loop. To make 'S' available outside of that loop, declare it *before* the loop:

```
String[] S = null;  // Declare it here and initialize it with a "dummy" value.
while((line = br.readLine()) !=null)
{
    :
    S[] = temp.split(" ");  // Assign the "real" value.
    :
}
// Now S will still be available for the rest of your method.
```